# Php can't read file with Shift JIS encoding

Tags: php, csv

i got an error about read csv file with encoding Shift_JIS when running on server. i tried follow this code below:

```
function readFile($file)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP.sjis');
    $ret = array();

    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
    while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
        mb_convert_variables('utf-8', 'sjis-win', $line);

        $ret[] = $line;
    }
    fclose($fp);

    return $ret;
}
```

When in localhost, i have no any problem, but when i running on server has no correct format.

This is content of file running on localhost (XAMPP):

Array

(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => カテゴリID
        [1] => ブランドID
        [2] => サイズID
        [3] => カラーID
        [4] => 状態
        [5] => 商品名
        [6] => 価格（税込）
        [7] => 商品説明
        [8] => 在庫数
        [9] => 送料個別設定
        [10] => 公開状態
    )
```

)

But running on server (centos):

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => JテゴリID
        [1] => uランドID
        [2] => TイズID
        [3] => JラーID
        [4] => 
        [5] => i名
        [6] => i（税込）
        [7] => i説明
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => J状態
    )
```

)

Please help me !

Comment: Anyone can help me ? This is important  for me.

Comment: I solved that problem, just upgrade php version to 5.6 on server.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to update PHP version, then you can update your PHP version to at least 5.6 then the problem is gone.

If not, do the following trick:

```
function getFilePointerUTF8($target_file){
    $current_locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, '0'); // Backup current locale.

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP.UTF-8');

    // Read the file content in SJIS-Win.
    $content = file_get_contents($target_file);

    // Convert file content to SJIS-Win.
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8", "SJIS-win");

    // Save the file as UTF-8 in a temp location.
    $fp = tmpfile();
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    rewind($fp);

    setlocale(LC_ALL, $current_locale); // Restore the backed-up locale.

    return $fp;
}
```

And using:

```
$fp = $this->getFileReaderUTF8("[your_file_location]"); // Ex: "~/data.csv"
$utf8_CSV_content = fgetcsv($fp);
```

Comment: Is there any way this can be applied to laravel-excel with laravel version 5.2?

Comment: I have a question I only want to apply this for shift-jis files however I want to check the contents of $content for the question mark character but the variable does not exist if the file is a shift-jis file which is very very bizzare